# How to use the axios library with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise, axios

#### Why axios callback changes are displayed in angularjs, without using $apply

I was trying [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) library on [angularjs](https://angularjs.org/) and I was surprised when I saw that the changes to `$scope` in the axios callback were detected by angular. I thought I had to call `$apply` like, for example, when you use `setTimeout`.

```
  // axios example
  axios.get(url).then((response) => {
    // Here I don't need $apply, why??
    $scope.axiosResult = response.data;
  });


  // setTimeout example
  setTimeout(() => {
    // Here I need $apply for the timeoutResult to appear on the HTML
    $scope.$apply(() => $scope.timeoutResult = {message: "timeout!"});
  }, 2000)
```

Do you know why `$apply` is not needed in axios?

EDIT:

[A comment by georgeawg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46521516/how-to-use-axios-with-angularjs#comment80004191_46522615) helped me see that I was using `$http` on another place, so I guess the digest cycle triggered by `$http` is helping axios callback to be "digested" too.

Comment: I never use $apply, and I use a bunch of 3rd party AngularJS modules. Did you try $timeout (AngularJS) instead of setTimeout?

Comment: My question was specifically why axios callback is participating in data-binding although I'm not using `$q` or `$apply`. I think I'm missing something about how angularjs works...

Answer (score 8):

## How to use the [axios library](https://github.com/axios/axios) with AngularJS

Bring its ES6 promises into the AngularJS context using [$q.when](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#when):

```
  // axios example
  ̶a̶x̶i̶o̶s̶.̶g̶e̶t̶(̶u̶r̶l̶)̶.̶t̶h̶e̶n̶(̶(̶r̶e̶s̶p̶o̶n̶s̶e̶)̶ ̶=̶>̶ ̶{̶
  $q.when(axios.get(url)).then((response) => {
    $scope.axiosResult = response.data;
  });
```

Only operations which are applied in the AngularJS execution context will benefit from AngularJS data-binding, exception handling, property watching, etc.

Also use the [$timeout service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout) instead of `setTimeout`.

```
  $timeout(() => {
    $scope.timeoutResult = {message: "timeout!"});
  }, 2000)
```

The [$timeout](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout) service is integrated with the AngularJS framework and its digest cycle.

Comment: Thank you! Although my question was specifically why axios callback is participating in data-binding although I'm not using `$q` or `$apply`.

Comment: You have not provided enough information to reproduce your results. I suspect something else in your code of which you are not aware is causing a digest cycle and the subsequent data binding.

Comment: Oh, I see! It's because I'm using `$http` on another place, and I guess the digest cycle triggered by `$http` is helping axios callback to be "digested" too. Thanks!